# Changing background color on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to allow users changing the background color by clicking one of the boxes.

[image: color boxes]

I came into this code but it doesn't work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul li a").click(function() {
    var Color = $(this).attr("data-color");
    $("body").css("background", Color);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="color-boxes">
  <li>
    <a data-color="#000000" class="Black" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-color="#7E392F" class="BurntHenna" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-color="#AE856C" class="TawnyBirch" href="#"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-color="#DAB58F" class="Sheepskin" href="#"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: the classes of the <a> element are simple the name of the color (pantone)

Comment: seems it is working properly. can you add minimum reproducible code snippet?

Comment: @adcoding we are missing some CSS. I answered because you seemed to miss the jQuery library but perhaps you did have that AND some CSS that would expand the links to something clickable

Answer (score 1):

We are missing some CSS in your question. I answer because you seemed to miss the jQuery library but perhaps you did have that AND some CSS that would expand the links to something clickable

This works if you add the jQuery library and some way to make the links visible, text or in this case display inline-block with a padding

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("ul li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // not strictly needed but a good idea
    const color = $(this).data("color");
    $("body").css("background", color);
  });
  $("[data-color]").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("li").css({"background-color": this.dataset.color})
  })
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:15px;
}

.color-boxes {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="color-boxes">
  <li>
    <a data-color="#000000" class="Black" href="#" title="Black"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-color="#7E392F" class="BurntHenna" href="#" title="BurntHenna"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-color="#AE856C" class="TawnyBirch" href="#" title="TawnyBirch"></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-color="#DAB58F" class="Sheepskin" href="#" title="SheepSkin"></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @adcoding i think you don't need text e.g. Black, BurntHenna, ...

Comment: @WilliamWang see update - I used padding and inline-block

Comment: @adcoding what's different between this code and your code other than adding jquery library?  Your code also worked fine with jquery library and css.

Comment: @freedomn-m without anything in the links, the links would not be clickable without extra css - perhaps adcoding HAD css like mine

Comment: @mplungjan I'm wondering what *adcoding* thinks is different to respond with "*it works*".  They provided a screenshot which showed *some* css and I (most likely incorrectly) assumed the html generated the screenshot - perhaps it was just a mock-up? The `a` (in OPs screenshot, assuming html generated) would be clickable in the same way as it is in your code (block+padding or block+dimensions as I did when checking OPs code)