# Change background color with JQuery problem

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have created boxes of different colors. When the user clicks on one of the box, the background color changes.
I found a code to do this and everything works fine.
But now the menu links no longer work.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="color-boxes">
        <div data-color="#000000" class="Black"></div>
        <div data-color="#7E392F" class="BurntHenna"></div>
        <div data-color="#AE856C" class="TawnyBirch"></div>
        <div data-color="#DAB58F" class="Sheepskin"></div>
    </div>

<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("div").click(function(){
                var Color = $(this).attr("data-color");
                $("body").css("background", Color);
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark">

        <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
            <img src="media/logo-bressana.png" width="250px" alt="">
        </a>

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">

            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="bio.html">Bio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="press.html">Press</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </nav>
```

Comment: What doesn't work ? Please elaborate

Comment: @Swati my menu links does nothing... when I click on it nothing happen instead of surf the page

Comment: Why you have `return false;` ? remove that and see everthing else in your code seems ok to me

Comment: @Swati omg. It was the `return false` making problems... thank you.
Now the links work fine

Comment: Change `$("div").click(function(){` to `$("div.color-boxes > div").click(function(){` - target your event handlers, never just use `$("div")`

Comment: @Swati the `return false` was there because older iterations (previously asked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64683117/changing-background-color-on-click) versions) of this question had the "colour-boxes" as `<a>` and the page was reloading without it.